# How can I find the code mvn dependency:analyze prompt me？

Tags: maven

all:
in my project ,I executed this maven command to analyze it's dependency

mvn dependency:analyze

it shows me the following message:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:analyze (default-cli) @ console ---
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.3:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.2:compile
[WARNING]    commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[WARNING]    com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.1:compile
[WARNING]    commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
```

How can I find which file used the specific jar?
commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile  e.g

Comment: can you please share your pom.xml

Comment: The pom is too large.There is some problems in the pom.But for this Ask,I just want to know "How can I find which file used the specific jar".

Comment: Best is to use `mvn dependency:tree` will show the structure and from which dependency a particular dependency is used.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is search for the packages or classes contained within that jar from the Eclipse search in the concerned project
`Search>File`